# How to create Listview gridlines in a LargeIcon view?

Tags: c#, listview

How to create Listview gridlines in a LargeIcon view using C# 2008?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation,

> The GridLines property has no effect unless the View property of the ListView control is set to Details."  That is, the control doesn't have any built-in support for drawing grid lines in LargeIcon view.  This kinda makes sense because the Details view is the only one which is actually grid-like -- the others don't have the row-and-column arrangement so it wouldn't be clear to the ListView where you wanted the lines to go.

You might be able to draw your own grid lines by overriding `OnPaintBackground`, but the docs note that `Paint()` is never called for a `ListView` (because it's drawn by the OS) so I wouldn't be optimistic.  Another possibility is to fake it using `BackgroundImage` and `BackgroundImageTiled`.

Comment: i already tried this BackgroundImage and BackgroundImageTiled. i tried the background image row & column lines. In the case when i scroll the listview item, the items are moved, but not moving backgroung images. in this situation looks very bad. what to do?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to interop down to the underlying Win32 ListView control.  I'm not sufficiently familiar to advise on details but I'd check out NM_CUSTOMDRAW (though this may be for item drawing only) and LVS_EX_TRANSPARENTBKGND (extended style, allows the parent to paint the background).  Sorry, I don't know enough to go into more detail.